# How can I recover my MultiBit HD wallet words?

Tags: wallet, multibit, backup, wallet-security

I have problem with MultiBit HD. Its balance changed to an unconfirmed transaction just like in this [bug report](https://github.com/keepkey/multibit-hd/issues/862).

It appears that I need to use my wallet words to recover the balance, but I have lost (totally lost, there is no chance of recovering) the wallet words. 
But given that I've got list of all possible words used in MultiBit HD and my wallet can I use it in some cracking program to find my words and their order in which they occur?

I do not have any experience with brute force or cracking, I'm just a regular, lame computer user.

Comment: Do you have both your wallet file and its password? In other words, do you simply need to extract your mnemonic sentence from your wallet for troubleshooting purposes (so you can try restoring it)?

Comment: Tnaky you very much. I have both wallet and password ,Can you provide some links with deals with my problem quite easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have both your wallet file (named `mbhd.wallet.aes` for MultiBit HD) and its password, you can use [this tool](https://github.com/gurnec/decrypt_bitcoinj_seed) to extract its mnemonic sentence/seed.

Note that the terms "brute force" and "crack" weren't the right ones to use, you're simply decrypting the wallet file. David's answer is correct in that you can't brute force a seed from scratch, but luckily that's not what you need to do here.

(Also, be sure to write your seed down somewhere once you have it! If you had lost your wallet file, you would have been out of luck...)

Comment: So using this too on my mhd.wallet.aes file, l I'll be able to se my wallet words and from there restore my wallet with these ? I hope, I understood that correctly :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you have any trouble with it, feel free to ask here or open an issue on GitHub. (FYI I'm the author of that tool.) Hope this helps!

Comment: So I've got python 2.7, and zip file, but I have no idea which of protobuff and pilibscypt files and correct and how to install them in python :/

Comment: Which operating system are you running?

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1 and downloaded python 2.7.12. But i cannot find the coresponding protobuff and pylibscript- Can you provide me some dircet links, please, I'm going in circles...

Comment: On Windows 8, just right-click on the `install-windows-requirements.ps1` file and click `Run with Powershell` to install them. Then double-click `decrypt_bitcoinj_seed.pyw` and choose your wallet file.

Answer (score 0):

No. The scheme is specifically designed to make this impossible. In fact, the only purpose of this scheme is to make sure the words cannot be cracked by brute force. If it didn't do that, what purpose would it serve?

You may be able to repair or recover you wallet file or extract the private key from it, but brute forcing the recovery from the words is impossible.